# How to filter out rows that contain two specific character strings in different (unspecified) columns?

Tags: r, subset

Given a set of 8 names, I want to generate all unique combinations of 5 names. However, certain names may not occur together.

How do I go about filtering out the rows that, for instance, combine "linda" and "susy" given the following example data?

```
# 7 names
names <- c("joe", "mark", "mary", "john", "linda", "susy", "peter", "annie")

# All unique combinations of 5 names
cbn <- t(combn(names, 5))
```

The actual data is much larger and there are more combinations that have to be excluded. Ideally, I'd like to find a short and tidy way to do this so that I have to adjust the code as little as possible if I need to make changes to the exclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a little function with two arguments: `data` and `x` that does what you are looking for

```
f <- function(data, x) {
  data[rowSums(`dim<-`(data %in% x, dim(data))) < length(x), ]
}
```

The function excludes rows where the values in `x` appear together.

Usage

```
x <- c("linda", "susy")
f(cbn, x)
```

Result

```
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4]    [,5]   
# [1,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "john"  "linda"
# [2,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "john"  "susy" 
# [3,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "john"  "peter"
# [4,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "john"  "annie"
# [5,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "peter"
# [6,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "annie"
# [7,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "peter"
# [8,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "annie"
# [9,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "peter" "annie"
#[10,] "joe"  "mark" "john"  "linda" "peter"
#[11,] "joe"  "mark" "john"  "linda" "annie"
#[12,] "joe"  "mark" "john"  "susy"  "peter"
#[13,] "joe"  "mark" "john"  "susy"  "annie"
#[14,] "joe"  "mark" "john"  "peter" "annie"
#[15,] "joe"  "mark" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[16,] "joe"  "mark" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[17,] "joe"  "mary" "john"  "linda" "peter"
#[18,] "joe"  "mary" "john"  "linda" "annie"
#[19,] "joe"  "mary" "john"  "susy"  "peter"
#[20,] "joe"  "mary" "john"  "susy"  "annie"
#[21,] "joe"  "mary" "john"  "peter" "annie"
#[22,] "joe"  "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[23,] "joe"  "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[24,] "joe"  "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[25,] "joe"  "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[26,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "peter"
#[27,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "annie"
#[28,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "peter"
#[29,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "annie"
#[30,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "peter" "annie"
#[31,] "mark" "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[32,] "mark" "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[33,] "mark" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[34,] "mark" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[35,] "mary" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[36,] "mary" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
```

---

You might use a for-loop when you have to check multiple combinations iteratively

```
x <- c("linda", "susy")
y <- c("joe", "john")
```

Create a list with those combinations

```
combs <- list(x, y)
```

Apply `f` (from above) in the loop

```
for(i in 1:length(combs)) {
  cbn <- f(cbn, combs[[i]])
}
```

Result

```
cbn
#      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4]    [,5]   
# [1,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "peter"
# [2,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "annie"
# [3,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "peter"
# [4,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "annie"
# [5,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "peter" "annie"
# [6,] "joe"  "mark" "linda" "peter" "annie"
# [7,] "joe"  "mark" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
# [8,] "joe"  "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
# [9,] "joe"  "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[10,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "peter"
#[11,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "annie"
#[12,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "peter"
#[13,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "annie"
#[14,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "peter" "annie"
#[15,] "mark" "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[16,] "mark" "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[17,] "mark" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[18,] "mark" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
#[19,] "mary" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
#[20,] "mary" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
```

Comment: That works really well! How would I proceed if there were multiple combinations to be excluded (e.g. also "joe" and "john")? Only thing I can think of is to write consecutive functions, but that just seems clunky.

Comment: So you would want a return value, i.e. matrix or data.frame for each combination, right?

Comment: I want a matrix or df that excludes all the rows that contain some defined combinations (e.g. exclude the pair linda & susy, and exclude the pair joe & john).

Comment: @NukeDude Updated my answer - hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Create names and combinations

```
names <- c("joe", "mark", "mary", "john", "linda", "susy", "peter", "annie")
cbn <- combn(names, 5)
```

Exclude rows with pairs

```
csums <- colSums((cbn == "linda") + (cbn == "susy"))
csums_2 <- colSums((cbn == "joe") + (cbn == "john"))
cbn <- t(cbn[, csums < 2 & csums_2 <2])
```

Results:

```
> cbn
      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4]    [,5]   
 [1,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "peter"
 [2,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "linda" "annie"
 [3,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "peter"
 [4,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "susy"  "annie"
 [5,] "joe"  "mark" "mary"  "peter" "annie"
 [6,] "joe"  "mark" "linda" "peter" "annie"
 [7,] "joe"  "mark" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
 [8,] "joe"  "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
 [9,] "joe"  "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
[10,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "peter"
[11,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "linda" "annie"
[12,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "peter"
[13,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "susy"  "annie"
[14,] "mark" "mary" "john"  "peter" "annie"
[15,] "mark" "mary" "linda" "peter" "annie"
[16,] "mark" "mary" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
[17,] "mark" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
[18,] "mark" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
[19,] "mary" "john" "linda" "peter" "annie"
[20,] "mary" "john" "susy"  "peter" "annie"
```